# Unable to access sharedpreferences after app close

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences, static-methods

I have a webrequest activity that makes requests to a webserver and stores the data.

When the app is used from login everything is fine. But once the app is closed and reopened any request to the server is met with the following error:

```
07-01 12:32:43.222: E/AndroidRuntime(29847): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.impact.main/com.impact.main.ActionsPopUpActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

This is the class im using to make the web requests:

```
public class WebRequest{

private static final String TAG = "WebRequest";

AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
public static SharedPreferences prefs;
public static SQLiteHandler db;
public static SessionManager session;

protected static Context context;

private static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;


public WebRequest(Context context){
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
} 
public static void Request(final String url, final String vars, final Boolean show, final String title, final String msg, final String requestName, final Boolean isLogin){


    session = new SessionManager(context);

    final ProgressDialog theProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    db = new SQLiteHandler(context);

    if(show == true){
        theProgressDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        theProgressDialog.setTitle(title);
        theProgressDialog.setMessage(msg);
        theProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        theProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        theProgressDialog.show();
    }

    StringRequest strreq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, url + vars, 
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "WEB Response: " + response.toString());


                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {


                            switch(requestName){
                               case "fetch_action_comments":

                                    JSONArray comments = jObj.getJSONArray("comments");

                                    // looping through All actions
                                    for (int i = 0; i < comments.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject comment =  comments.getJSONObject(i);

                                        if(comment.has("comments") && !comment.getString("comments").equals("empty")){



                                            int commentCheck = db.getRowCount("*", dbTables.TABLE_ACTIONCOMMENTS, "WHERE actioncommentid='" + comment.getString("actioncommentid") + "'");

                                            if(commentCheck == 0){
                                                String[][] commentValues = {
                                                        { dbTables.KEY_ACTIONCOMMENTID,  comment.getString(dbTables.KEY_ACTIONCOMMENTID)  },
                                                        { dbTables.KEY_ACTIONID,   comment.getString(dbTables.KEY_ACTIONID)   },
                                                        { dbTables.KEY_COMMENT,   comment.getString(dbTables.KEY_COMMENT)   },
                                                        { dbTables.KEY_ADDEDBY,    comment.getString(dbTables.KEY_ADDEDBY)    },
                                                        { dbTables.KEY_DATEADDED,  comment.getString(dbTables.KEY_DATEADDED)  },
                                                        { dbTables.KEY_EDITEDBY,   comment.getString(dbTables.KEY_EDITEDBY)   },
                                                        { dbTables.KEY_DATEEDITED, comment.getString(dbTables.KEY_DATEEDITED) },
                                                        { dbTables.KEY_USERID, comment.getString(dbTables.KEY_USERID) }
                                                    };
                                                    db.insert(dbTables.TABLE_ACTIONCOMMENTS, commentValues);
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }    
                                break;
}

                            if(show == true){
                                theProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }else{
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            if(errorMsg.length() > 0){
                                Toast.makeText(context, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            if(show == true){
                                theProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        Toast.makeText(context, e+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(show == true){
                            theProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Web Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(show == true){
                        theProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });



    // Adding request to request queue
    addToRequestQueue(strreq, requestName);


}


public static RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public static <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}

}
```

The request is called in the onCreate part of another Activity.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;

public class SessionManager {
// LogCat tag
private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

Editor editor;
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "Login";

private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN = "isLoggedIn";

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    //should check null because in air plan mode it will be null 
    return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());

} 

public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {

    editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, isLoggedIn);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();

    Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
}

public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);
}
}
```

Comment: Since it's already an activity why you need to get context of other one ? or just make it as an ordinary class by remove extends Activity .

Comment: where u are using `getSharedPreferences` method? please share relative code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I've added more relavant code

Comment: @jampez77: please show code where u are using `WebRequest` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you are calling `WebRequest.Request()` without first calling `new WebRequest()`.  The static method `Request()` depends on the static field `context` which is only set in the constructor of `WebRequest()`.  Your `static` methods need to be stand-alone and not require the object to be constructed to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Write Editor object as

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```